# Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse

Tags: php, mysql, json, angular, ionic-framework

I made my RESTful mysql backend everything is good **except that** my 
feteched query has problem.I mean ,it show me nothing when my returned json is more than 2 objects.
I'm working with ionic3 / http.

my select.php:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     $data = array() ;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "0";
}
```

my service file in ionic:

```
getProducts(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost/api/products/select.php")
    .map(res=>{
      this.checkMe = res;

      if(this.checkMe._body !== "0"){
         return res.json()
      }

    } );
  }
```

I realy need your help.
Thank you all.

Comment: I suggest you focus on one problem at a time. Just open select.php in your browser and make that work before even involving ionic. Makes no sense spending time debugging in js if the problem is in the php

Comment: - first check that particular php file getting call (just past that url direct to address bar, or use any debugging tool for your browser to monitor the request and responce status) - then echo some plain text in php file to verify that it works upto here. - then after call query var_dump() the data to verify thats good. - next verify json encode() returning valid json. hope helps

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to do ..

```
getProducts(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost/api/products/select.php")
    .map(res=>{
      this.checkMe = res.json() as any;

      if(this.checkMe._body !== "0"){
         return res.json()
      }

    } );
  }
```

Comment: I'm realy glad that you answered my problem.
I found the solution.
the prob was:
I had html <tag> into one of me fields that stop the json_encode() operation.

Answer (score 0):

I had **html tag** into one of me fields in the MySQL that stops the json_encode() operation.

---

Thanks you all